# Savefig not saving axes for png file

Tags: python, plot, axes, savefig

I'm having a trouble when trying to save plot to png file. When I tried with `.jpg`, everything was alright. So, the problem is that graph is not saved with axes and axes' titles, there is only the content. How to save it so everything is preserved?

[image: code from below side-by-side with resulting graph1.png]

```py
#creating a scatter plot
fig = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='sentimentscore', y='sentimentmagnitude', c = col)
plt.axvline(0, 0, 10, color = "grey") #creating vertical dividing line
plt.xlabel('Sentiment score')
plt.ylabel('Sentiment magnitude')
plt.title('Sentiment analysis')
fig.set_ylim([3, 15])
#annotating points with track numbers
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.annotate(track[i], (x[i] - 0.002, y[i] + 0.25)) 

fig.figure.savefig("transparentgraph1.png", transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight', dpi=200)
fig.figure.savefig("graph1.png", bbox_inches='tight', dpi=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

PNGs support transparency. The axes and axes' titles are there, you just don't see them in your image viewer because they are black text on transparent background. Adding the following line before saving your figure should fix your problem:

```py
fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:white') # make transparent background white
```